# how to compare Frame and button width and length?

Tags: java, swing, frame

in swing environment , i draw button and set action to move on my frame.
when my button reached the corner of frame or button and frame length and width are equals ; do other action or something like that.
my problem is i cant find any Component to compare the button and frame location or length and width .

```
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            x= x + 10 ;
            y=y + 10 ;
            jButtonMove.setLocation(x, y);
    }
    };
    Timer t = new Timer(500 , al);
    t.start();
```

Comment: if (button.getWidth() + button.locationX() < frame.getWidth()) {doSmth();} This principle. The same for left border and height.

Comment: @shved90 thnx for reply .

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [Component.getX()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getX%28%29) and [Component.getY()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getY%28%29) for getting **X and Y Co-ordinates**. [Component.getWidth()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getWidth%28%29) and [Component.getHeight()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getHeight%28%29), for getting **Width and Height** of the said component.

Here is the sample code for further help :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LocationExample {

    private JButton button;
    private JTextField tField;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Location Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("Useless");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                tField.setText("X : " + tField.getX() + 
                                " Y : " + tField.getY() +
                                " Width : " + tField.getWidth() +
                                " Height : " + tField.getHeight());
                System.out.println("X : " + button.getX() + 
                                    " Y : " + button.getY() + 
                                    " Width : " + button.getWidth() + 
                                    " Height : " + button.getHeight());
            }
        });
        tField = new JTextField("Useless", 10);

        contentPane.add(button);
        contentPane.add(tField);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LocationExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```